# Is it faster to perform a cascade of `if`s or to union two subqueries filtered queries?

Tags: sql, apache-spark

I'm writing a Spark SQL query, and asking myself if for the SQL optimization engine it is easier to perform a

```
SELECT key
  , IF(key IN list, value1, value1 + 1]) AS value1
  , IF(key IN list, value2, value2 + 1) AS value2
  , IF(key IN list, value3, value3 + 1) AS value3
FROM ATable
```

or

```
WITH case1 AS (
SELECT key
  , value1 AS value1
  , value2 AS value2
  , value3 AS value3
FROM ATable
)
  , case2 AS (
SELECT key
  , value1 + 1 AS value1
  , value2 + 1 AS value2
  , value3 + 1 AS value3
FROM ATable
)
SELECT * FROM case1
UNION ALL
SELECT * FROM case2
```

In my opinion the second way is more readable if the list of `IF`s is long, but don't know if creating two tables generates more overhead.

Comment: These statements do not do the same thing.  You should use the one that actually accomplishes what you want to do.  And, for the record, most people would consider the first form much more readable.

Answer (score 0):

It seems you missed WHERE clause in second case. Without `WHERE` (`key in LIST`, `key NOT IN list )`, second query will produce x2 rows.

Even with WHERE, it will be two scans of table in second query, though it will be done in parallel, it will create 2x more load.

Only facts, not opinion: 1st is much shorter, 1st query guaranteed to scan table only one time.

Even if case1 and case2 together return less rows than the whole table contains, replacing `UNION ALL` with `OR` conditions in `WHERE` is more performant solution.